# Create navigation page with 3 diagonal image strips

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a navigation page where 3 images are displayed as diagonal stripes.  My first approach was to use div's and to transform -webkit-transform: skew into shape. The problem is that the first and last image leaves a lot of free space.

My second approach would be to use canvas because it allows me to define the shape freely. 
I'm not sure if I can use the images as buttons(onclick event) because the shape would be correct, but the div will remain rectangular. With the consequence that if for example the middle image is clicked and the middle div overlap the first div the first function of the first image is triggered.

Do you know a good way to solve this problem? Do you have a better approach?

The idea:
[The stripes should have the +- the same size. Unlike my sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtpH7.png)

[image]
As requested here the code fragment. Unfortunately there is not much, as I haven't found a clever approach yet:

```css
html, body{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    
}

:root{
    --preset-screen-width: 1024px;
    --preset-screen-height: 768px;
    --main-img-width: calc((var(--preset-screen-width) / 3) - 5px);
}
/*
.Hidden-Images {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
}
*/
.Hidden-Image_1{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-image: url(../img/redhead.jpg);
    background-size: 1024px 768px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
} 

.Hidden-Image_2{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-image: url(../img/brownhead.jpg);
    background-size: 1024px 768px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
} 

.Hidden-Image_3{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-image: url(../img/loecklihead.jpg);
    background-size: 1024px 768px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
}

.Image-Stripes-Holder{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgb(93, 129, 39);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.First-Image-Holder{
    width: var(--main-img-width);
    height: var(--preset-screen-height);
    border: red 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Second-Image-Holder{
    width: var(--main-img-width);
    height: var(--preset-screen-height);
    border: blue 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Third-Image-Holder{
    width: var(--main-img-width);
    height: var(--preset-screen-height);
    border: green 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CH.Valette_S1.C1_2019.1850-DE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/valette_custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modules/essential/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/noBouncing/noBouning.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/fastSwipe/fastSwipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/essential/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/fastSwipe/_vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/essential/veeva-lib/veeva-library-3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/fastSwipe/_vendor/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/fastSwipe/accelerator/lib/touchy.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/fastSwipe/_vendor/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/essential/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Hidden-Images">
        <div class="Hidden-Image_1">
   
        </div>
        <div class="Hidden-Image_2">
      
        </div>
        <div class="Hidden-Image_3">
   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Image-Stripes-Holder">
        <div class="First-Image-Holder">
            <!--<img class="First-Image" src="assets/img/redhead_small.jpg">-->
        </div>
        <div class="Second-Image-Holder">
            <!--<img class="First-Image" src="assets/img/brownhead_small.jpg">-->
        </div>
        <div class="Third-Image-Holder">
            <!--<img class="First-Image" src="assets/img/loecklihead_small.jpg">-->
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have done something similar to this chk this out https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/rev6txpe/

Comment: Hey. Thanks for welcoming. As wished I added the Code.

Comment: Take a look at `clip-path` in css

Comment: @ThomasScheffer Thanks for your input. This could really work. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a map in your HTML to define click areas. Done this in the past and it works perfectly.

Remember to use
    `<area shape="poly">` for the map and define coordinates for click areas.

More detailed reading with an example can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_area_tag.htm).